# Guideline to uninstall something and install something

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I want to do a project with html as a front end and PHP as a back end.
but unfortunately i installed apache2,mysql,php5 and all without proper guideline.. so now nothing working fine...
SO please guide me to uninstall everything and help me to configure everything from the stating.......
Project requirement
Front end : HTML
back end : PHP
database : MYSQL

Comment: How did you install all of that? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To remove: `sudo apt-get purge apache2 mysql php5`

For install: Make sure you did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then for Ubuntu 16.04 and later:`sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql mysql-server`

For Ubuntu 15.04 and earlier: `sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server`

There are many guides how to install the LAMP-Stack correctly. A good one is this here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04